# How do I run keyframe animations on a div only after the completion of a high resolution image inside that div?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Currently the keyframe animation fadeIn runs immediately after the page has been loaded but I only want this keyframe animation to run only after the the load completion of that high resolution image inside that .image div?How do I do that?

Is there any solution using jquery for this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/mixin/6zeBF/

```
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
    @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
    @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.image{
    opacity:0;  
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

<div id="content">

    <div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uIn74U7.png" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){   
    $('div > div').addClass('image');
});
```

From the docs:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

ref: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/